# idiomatic Makefile and command arguments

Tags: docker, makefile, docker-compose, gnu-make

### Context

I have a Makefile to run `docker`-ized service

```
RUN = docker-compose run $(ARGS) --rm serivce

.PHONY: shell
shell:
    ${RUN} /bin/sh

.PHONY: server
server:
    $(eval ARGS=--service-ports) ${RUN}
```

### Problem

`server` task needs additional arguments(`--service-ports`) set to start the container.
Just hardcoding the arguments into the `RUN` wont work because `shell` would publish port as well and will fail(having the `server` running).

### Question

What's the idiomatic way to specify arguments `ARGS` depending on the context?

`$(eval ARGS=--service-ports)` works but is there a "right way"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `eval` is definitely not right.  What if someone runs `make server shell`?  Now the `shell` will have that argument set, because the `eval` resets it globally.

Is there some reason you can't just write:

```
server:
         $(RUN) --service-ports
```

?  In general if you need a variable customized on a per-target basis you have two options:

You can use [target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html):

```
server: ARGS = --service-ports
server:
         $(RUN)
```

Or you can use [recursively-expanded variables](http://make.mad-scientist.net/recursive-expansion/):

```
server_ARGS = --service-ports

RUN = docker-compose run $($@_ARGS) --rm service

server:
         $(RUN)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simply split your variables up into more parts:

```
COMMAND = docker-compose run --rm $(ARGS)
CONTAINER = service

.PHONY: shell
shell:
    ${COMMAND} ${CONTAINER} /bin/sh

.PHONY: server
server:
    ${COMMAND} --service-ports ${CONTAINER}
```